# Database Normalization into 2NF

Tags: database, normalization

I've been given a potential solution to a database. One of the entities I have is called 'Order', it includes attributes:

- Sum_Of_Req
- Served_By
- Service_Name
- Customer_Feedback
- Customer_Email
- Requirement_Date
- Served_Time

I need to find a composite key so I'm able to put this relation into 2NF (so every attribute is fully functionally dependant on the primary key (which in this case I feel will be a composite key)). However I don't see which two could uniquely identify an order.

Please note: I'm unable to add 'Order#' or of the like. Unfortunately (although completely obvious and simple) my lecturer specifically stated that we're not allowed to use unique IDs.

Comment: Customer_Email and Served_Time? That is assuming that these mean 'ordered by X at time Y' and that this defines an order in a unique way. You should include more info on what each column represents and what you have tried so far (and why you think it does not work).

Comment: @Sam Honestly he's given us no explanation of the attributes so I'm as clueless as you. But, I feel like that is a good answer and would uniquely identify an order. However, Customer_Email is the primary key of another entity, can you have a composite key of a foreign key and a primary key??

Answer (score 0):

In order to get to 2NF you need to define the primary key as composite of:

**Served_time, Served_by, Service_Name, Customer_Email**

Example data for one relation:

- **Served_Time**: '10:30'
- **Served_By**: 'Joe'
- **Service_Name**: 'Service_a'
- **Customer_Email**: 'email@abd.com'
- Customer_Feedback: 'Nice service !!'
- Requirement_Date: '42368'
- Sum_Of_Req: '5'

Comment: Why would you need served by? Wouldn't the time suffice? As I don't see when a cashier could process 2 orders at the exact same time.

Comment: You need "served by", because there could be multiple orders for the same customer by different agents. 
You need "served_time" because the same agent will have multiple orders for the same customer.
In theory he could process multiple orders at the same time. or at least they might be recorded in the system at the same time, so you cant rely on served_time only.

Comment: But would that be in the 2nd Normal form now? As I don't think that the Sum_Of_Request is dependant on who serves them, nor the customer.

Comment: Based on the information I have I believe that "sum_of-Req" is part of this order. It could e.g. describe the number of request items in the order. So it is fully dependent on the primary key I proposed.

Comment: But it's not fully functionally dependant on the other two? For it to be in 2NF, does it not have to rely on all candidate keys?

Comment: No, "sum_of-req" must only be functionally dependent on the primary key candidate to be 2NF. If it were functionally dependent on one or both of the other attributes (Customer_feedback, Requirement Date) than it would not be in 2NF.